# C standards and POSIX compliance

Tags: c, posix, standards, c-standard-library

So I have a few very closely related questions (sequential).

- Is POSIX managed by the C standard committee or is it merely a standard to enable cross-platform functionalities?
- Are the standards released with disregard to POSIX?
- If you're working on some new chip / os and are creating a non-POSIX compliant C implementation for that system, is your os considered portable (since you're complying to the C standard)?
- Will the C standards and POSIX standards stay separate in the future?

Big thanks to anyone who has read my question, and of course to anyone who has written an answer.

Comment: @MortenJensen Not all of them, so I'm going to update my question. Would you mind removing the feedback please? (if you see fit)

Comment: Short answer, POSIX and C-Standard and apples and oranges. Both fruit, but quite different.

Comment: @MortenJensen I've updated my answer, you can check it out now.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I've updated my question, but thanks for the answer. I'm just trying to understand that very difference.

Comment: They are different standards. See [POSIX Standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/) and you know were the C-Standard lives. In C you will have a number of functions provided by POSIX as an extension to the C-Standard library. This is the difference between "Strictly Conforming" (C-Standard Only) or "Conforming", C plus other standards. Strictly conforming guarantees portability.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin You said Strictly Conforming means C Standard Only, but then said that Strictly Conforming guarantees portability. Isn't the whole purpose of POSIX to enable portability?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin So if you want pure standard C, and want to target as many platforms as possible (including old ones), should you divert from POSIX defined stuff?

Comment: The standards approach portability from different angles. C-standard is specific to C, POSIX covers a number of areas as well. Just as you wouldn't look to the C-standard to determine Shell portability, you don't look at POSX to determine C portability. They serve different purposes. (and there is the historical hodge-podge of features from many sources, BSD, Unix, etc that POSIX sought to address in its standard). Take the POSIX function `strdup()`, it isn't part of the C-standard library, but many compilers provide it. You can look at the `CONFORMING TO` section of the man-page for help.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Excellent explanation, thanks a lot!